# how to change the entry's text when I click on the entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, python-class

I have this entry class:

```
class my_entry(Entry):
def __init__(self,the_window):
    Entry.__init__(self,the_window)
    def changeText(Event):
        self["text"]="the new text"
        print("text changed")
    self.bind("<Button-1>", changeText)
```

Now when I click on the entry it prints: `text changed`,but the text don't change...

I have many entrys so I can't use the `set` like:`my_entry1.set("new text")` for each entry

how can I change the entry's text from the class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Text In Entry (Tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847622/updating-text-in-entry-tkinter). Read up on [The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: as I said I have many entrys so I want one "function" for all of them- or to make it from the class

Comment: ***"many entrys ... one "function""***: `<entry>.bind(...` callbacks are working with many widgets as you get the reference from `event.widget`: Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: The answer can be found in readily available documentation. Read up on the `insert` and `delete` methods of the entry widget, as well as what the `event` object provides in bound functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do this:

```
class my_entry(Entry):
    def __init__(self,the_window):
        Entry.__init__(self,the_window)
        def changeText(Event):
            self.delete(0,END)
            self.insert(0,"new text")
            print("text changed")
        self.bind("<Button-1>", changeText)
```